# How to perform repeated iterative actions on DOM elements using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.myclass').each(function () {
  totalWidth += $(this).width();
});
```

Now after I have done this I want to perform another action on each individual `$('.myclass')` element, e.g.

```
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  // use computed totalWidth for something else
});
```

How can I do that? Won't the second attempt to select the elements create some problem?

Comment: You mean you want to use two `each` methods the same time? Why do that?

Comment: No it won't. As long at the 2 .each statement are one after another, they have nothing to do with each other. The selection or .each does not effect others of this type.

Comment: `Won't the second attempt to select the elements create some problem?` No not at all, although there may be another way to avoid using two loops. Could you show a small snippet of your HTML and a description of what you need to do with the `totalWidth` value

Comment: @KobyDouek do you mean `$('.myclass').each(function(){ ... }).each(function(){ ... });` or should they not be chained but separate?

Comment: Yes, keep them separated and not nested.

Comment: @KobyDouek - by 'not nested' you mean not chained? Sorry for asking again, I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It seems there are 2 opinions on that. Could someone please clarify?

Comment: The opinions were the same. Nested = `$.each(function() { $.each(...`, chained = `$.each().each()`. In this case, use chained.

Comment: If you want to sum a value, you cannot nest the 2 loops, 1 inside the other - It's more elegant to create 2 different loops, one who calculates and one to use the calculated value.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Then it should be chained and that's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, selecting the elements again won't create any problems, although it does spend some unnecessary time searching for elements that you have already found. You can prevent this by using chained `.each` calls, like so:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$('.myclass').each(function() {
  totalWidth += $(this).width();
}).each(function() {
  // use computed totalWidth for something else
});
```

Or, if you need to do some intermediate operations between the two loops, you can store the jQuery collection in a variable:

```
var totalWidth = 0;
var $myclass = $('.myclass').each(function() {
  totalWidth += $(this).width();
});
// do other stuff
$myclass.each(function() {
  // use computed totalWidth for something else
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what the comments in the questions said.